# Inserting data into table using java

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I want to insert user related information into table(users),When i am creating the form i have used drop-down list.There are two tables(users and department) in my database.I want to show the name of all the departments of table department in the drop down list(so that the user selects that department name) and insert into table users. How should i do this?

file name-c_user.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>create</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Create User</h1>
    <br>
    <h2><a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a></h2>
    <br>
    <h3><a href='success.jsp'>Go Back</a></h3>
    <form method="post" action="registration.jsp">
        <center>
        <table border="1" width="30%" cellpadding="3">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Login Here</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>User Name :</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="uname" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>User Id :</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="uid" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Department :</td>
                    <td><select name="departments">
                            <option></option>
                            <option></option>
                        </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email Id :</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mobile No. :</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="mobile" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password :</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="pass" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
                    <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
        </center>
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

file name-registration.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%
String user = request.getParameter("uname");  
String id = request.getParameter("uid");
String email = request.getParameter("email");
String mobile = request.getParameter("mobile");    
String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");   
String department="";


Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con =    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login",
        "root", "root");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
//ResultSet rs;
int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into users(uname, id, department, email,   mobile, pass) values ('" + user + "','" + id + "','" + department + "','" +   email + "','" + mobile + "','" + pwd + "')");
if (i > 0) {
    //session.setAttribute("userid", user);
    response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
   // out.print("Registration Successfull!"+"<a href='index.jsp'>Go to   Login</a>");
} else {
    response.sendRedirect("c_user.jsp");
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: there is no problem i just want to know how to display the options of drop down list from department table and insert it in users table.

Comment: Your code has a lot of security issues regarding the database connection. You should look into SQL injection and prepared statements. Also, the database user shouldn't be root, neither the password.

Comment: it is my first time using database connection and this is only rough for my practice that is why i have simply taken user and password as root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all change column `department` to `departmentid` in `users` table and make foreign key in `users` table and use `department` table as a reference table

then after 
just do this code on your page `c_user.jsp`

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>create</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Create User</h1>
        <br>
        <h2><a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a></h2>
        <br>
        <h3><a href='success.jsp'>Go Back</a></h3>
        <form method="post" action="registration.jsp">
            <center>
            <table border="1" width="30%" cellpadding="3">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Login Here</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>User Name :</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="uname" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>User Id :</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="uid" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Department :</td>
                        <td><select name="departments">
    <%try{
    String sql="select * from department";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login",
            "root", "root");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rs.next()){
    %>                          
      <option value="<%=rs.getInt("departmentid")%>"><%=rs.getString("departmentname")%></option>
<%}
    rs.close();
    st.close();
    con.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }%>
                              </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Email Id :</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Mobile No. :</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="mobile" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password :</td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="pass" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
                        <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
            </center>
        </form>
     </body>
    </html>
```

then after submit this `departmentid` will be stored in `users` table  and don't miss to change query of insert  like this
 change insert query in `registration.jsp` page

```
insert into users(uname, id, departmentid, email,   mobile, pass) values ('" + user + "','" + id + "','" + departmentid + "','" +   email + "','" + mobile + "','" + pwd + "')
```

Comment: do i have to create a primary key in table department before creating foreign key in users table

Comment: yeah you have to define `departmentid` as a primary key and that `departmentid` of `deparment` table is reference column of `departmentid` of `users` table

Comment: i using mysql command:-alter table login.users add foreign key(departmentid) references login.file;                                                                  but it is showing cannot add foreign key constraint . i dom't know why?

Comment: your `departmentid` column's datatype in **users** table must be same as in `departmentid` column's datatype in **department** table and your `departmentid` in **department** table must be define as a primary key

Comment: your create query on **department** table should be like this **`CREATE TABLE `department` (
  `departmentid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `departmentname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`departmentid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
`**

Comment: your create query on **users** table should be like this **`CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `deparmentid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_users_key1_idx` (`deparmentid`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_key1` FOREIGN KEY (`deparmentid`) REFERENCES `department` (`departmentid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;`**

Answer (score 2):

```
<select>
<%
         ResultSet rs1=state.executeQuery(" select department from your table");
                             while(rs.next()){

                            %>

          <option value="<%rs.getString(1)"%>><%rs.getString(1)"%></option>


    <%}%>
</select>
try this code
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ajax call to display the department name in ui and insert suitable it into your users table